# node.js where to put util functions used by backend and frontend

Tags: node.js, directory-structure

Node.js is special because the backend and frontend use the same language. I wanted to take advantage of this and only write 1 set of util functions (universal functions like numToPercent) for backend and frontend. Here is how my (important) files are structured right now:

```
project
  public
    index.html
    index.js
  scripts
    script1.js
  index.js
  otherScript.js
```

Where is the canonical location to put my util file?

Edit: to make this more specific, is there a "shared" folder or something to put this file? Because otherwise public seems like the best place to put this

Comment: This is more a question of taste. You can put it wherever you want unless you use a special framework (like NextJS) which has special rules. In your exmple how about scripts folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can package the shared code and add it as a dependency via npm.